# Grouping by where different than?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query that will group results BY where the grouped by field is not empty.
My query goes like this:

the thing is that all the rows where the created_by_alias is empty are grouped into one, which is not good. I need to group only where the value is different than ''.

I cannot change the field to be NULL by default because of some reasons (the website is on joomla and in order to do this i'll have to change the core).

```
SELECT c.created_by_alias, c.introtext,c.id,c.publish_up,c.publish_down 
FROM jos_content as c 
GROUP BY c.created_by_alias
```

Is such thing possible?

Thanks for your time and knowledge :)

### example :

| name      |       groupMe            |

```
---------------------------------------
| aaa       |           XX             |
---------------------------------------
| aaa       |           XX             |
---------------------------------------
| ccc       |                          |
--------------------------------------- 
| ddd       |                          |
---------------------------------------

I would like to receive such results:
---------------------------------------
| aaa       |           XX             |
---------------------------------------
| ccc       |                          |
--------------------------------------- 
| ddd       |                          |
---------------------------------------

I hope
```

Comment: Did you try ot use "WHERE  c.created_by_alias is not null"

Comment: Can you provide example data and the result you expect to receive? The question is a bit confusing. Thanks

Comment: @Oyeme - Hi, thanks but it will retrieve only answers where the field is not empty, and I want them too....

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho I'll update my question and add such info

Comment: Finally I understood it. Please also add any restriction regarding the query @ypercube 's solution works, but I don't understand why you are not marking it as correct. Only one WHERE clause is allowed? Is there any limit on the INNER JOINS too?

Comment: The only restriction is that is that I must have the query formed as a single WHERE (in ypercube it had two queries that needed the same WHERE statement). except for that I think I can add as many joins as I like, but I don't all the possible SQL syntaxes and functions good enough to be 100% sure before I try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  SELECT c.created_by_alias, ...   
  FROM jos_content as c 
  WHERE c.created_by_alias <> ''
  GROUP BY c.created_by_alias
UNION ALL
  SELECT c.created_by_alias, ...   
  FROM jos_content as c 
  WHERE c.created_by_alias = ''
```

Another way would be:

```
  SELECT c.created_by_alias, ...   
  FROM jos_content as c 
  GROUP BY c.created_by_alias
         , CASE WHEN c.created_by_alias = '' 
                  THEN c.PK                  --- the Primary Key
                  ELSE NULL
           END
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... My problem is that I cannot use this without major changes to the joomla core as the WHERE is dynamically created and in order to update two WHERE statement i'll need to change the way the $WHERE array is embedded into the query - and this will be erased the next time I update the Joomla version :\ thanks for the good idea though it works except for my specific problem...

Comment: LOL! Just posted the same thing... I run away from NULL values because Yanipan scared me with those joomla restrictions :P

Comment: It seems quite promising but it dosn't always work, i'm trying to figure when exactly it fails, might be something in my implementation...

Answer (score 4):

What about?

```
select name, count(*) from t1
group by name, if (name = '', id, -1)
```

Comment: hey mate, thanks for your help but just managed to pull off the answer above. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

I might be overlooking something in your question, but wouldn't it be just a `WHERE`-condition, something like...

```
SELECT c.created_by_alias, c.introtext,c.id,c.publish_up,c.publish_down 
FROM jos_content as c
WHERE c.created_by_alias != "" 
GROUP BY c.created_by_alias
```

...?

If I'm wrong, please provide some sample data in order to see more clearly what you want to archive.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The problem with the WHERE is that it will not return the rows where c.created_by_alias is empty, and I need them too. I only want to remove (group) rows where the field above is not empty... thanks